# Trying to make a Boolean the Word True or False

Tags: python, boolean

My simple Python program is working right--it is printing a -1 for false--but how do I make it print the word False in the place of -1?

```
import sys
text= sys.argv[1]
red= "red"
# Write your code here

def isred():
  print(text.find(red))

isred()
```

It prints -1 but need it to print "True" or "False".

Comment: As John says, `in` is simpler, and it's a little faster. Only use `.find` when you need to get the index of the substring.

Answer (score 5):

```
print(text.find(red) >= 0)
```

Or, simpler:

```
print(red in text)
```

Comment: Worked!!!! Is that a function of Python i missed >= 0 returns the word true or false?